# How to specify a path on a different drive with VS2008 devenv.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

It seems that it doesn't understand something like "/d D:\solution.sln", which is a problem. How would I specify a path on a different drive? Can I somehow avoid this altogether and just refer to a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does work without problems if you omit the '/d' (not sure what that is supposed to do). Invoke 'devenv /?' to see available options, for example:

```
devenv d:\solution.sln /build /project myproject
```

builds only project 'myproject' from that solution; you can omit the solution if you want to:

```
devenv d:\myproject.vcproj /build
```

does exactly the same

Comment: Turns out I mispelled the file name :facepalm: